# How to call a decorator (instance method) of other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I have a class called `RMath()` which takes 2 values `a` and `b`. Then there is a function named `add()` which sums up these `a` and `b`. Now i want to record the calculation time. I decided to use decorator here without touching the original function. At the same time, i don't want to write this decorator in the same class, So i have created a new class as `Handler`, and created an instance method as `timeit`. But when i am trying to use this decorator as `@Handler.timeit`, it throws an error `TypeError: timeit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

```
import time

class Handlers():

    def timeit(self, func):
        def timefunc():
            start = time.time()
            func()
            end = time.time()
            print('Time taken: ', end - start)
        return timefunc()

class RMath():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Handlers.timeit
    def add(self):
        try:
            self.a + self.b
        except Exception as e:
            return e

a = 10
b = 20
m = RMath(a, b)
c = m.add()
print(c)
```

At least from the error i could see there is some issue with `@Handlers.timeit`

Could someone please help me to understand the issue?

Even if i remove self from decorator as `def timeit(func):` it is throwing error: `TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: even if i remove self from decorator as `def timeit(func):` it is throwing error: TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: is the `()` after the class name necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` in this case. Here's how I'd approach it:

```py
from functools import wraps
from time import time


class Handlers:

    @staticmethod
    def timeit(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def timed_func(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time()
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time()
            print(f'[{func.__qualname__}] Time taken: {end - start}')

            return ret

        return timed_func


class RMath:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Handlers.timeit
    def add(self):
        try:
            # add a `return` here!
            return self.a + self.b
        except Exception as e:
            return e


a = 10
b = 20
m = RMath(a, b)
c = m.add()
print(c)
```

Out:

```
[RMath.add] Time taken: 3.0994415283203125e-06
30
```

---

**Update:** the `*args, **kwargs*` is a generalized approach to handle a function that takes any number of parameters, however if you explicitly just to want to support the `RMath.add()` method - a function which takes a single parameter `self` - you can use a slightly different approach as below:

```py
@wraps(func)
def timed_func(self):
    start = time()
    ret = func(self)
    end = time()
    print(f'[{func.__qualname__}] Time taken: {end - start}')

    return ret
```

Comment: Honestly speaking i am still to explore functools that i will. But is there any way to achieve this in which i demonstrated. is this how python is designed?

Comment: Thanks, but why to use `*args, **kwargs`?

Comment: @TarunK the functools usage is optional, but it is best practice because I think it carries over original func docs and other stuff. The `*args, **kwargs` is a generalized approach to handle functions that take multiple params or input values. It could also just be `self` since this is the only param that the add method takes, however in this case I opted to generalize it so that it could be applied to other functions if needed.

Comment: surprising it is not working without `*args, **kwargs`. I thought if it is just `self` we dont need to explicitly handle the args by using `*args, **kwargs` but in this case it is forcing me to use `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: I updated my answer to mention an alternate approach, but note that the `*args, **kwargs` is not mandatory. If you wanted to, you could update it to just `self` and then pass it in to the function, since it requires this param to be passed in also.

Answer (score 2):

There are many smaller things that needs to be fixed to make this work. You have to return the inner function from your decorator, not the result of calling the function. You also have to marshal the arguments given to the original function through your function - and you need to return the result from your wrapped function after computing the time spent.

And since you never create a `Handler` instance, you should define the wrapping function as a static method (it'll still work even if you don't do this, but there will be no `self`).

```py
import time

class Handlers():
    # make sure we don't require an instance
    @staticmethod
    def timeit(func):
        def timefunc(*args, **kwargs):
            #        ^--- needs to accept and marshal the arguments
            start = time.time()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # ^- keep result ^--- marshal the arguments
            end = time.time()
            print('Time taken: ', end - start)
            return result
            # ^- return the result of calling the wrapped function

        return timefunc
        # ^-- return the function, not the result of calling the function


class RMath():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @Handlers.timeit
    def add(self):
        try:
            return self.a + self.b
            # ^--- needs to return the result of the addition
        except Exception as e:
            return e

a = 10
b = 20
m = RMath(a, b)
c = m.add()
print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do we need to accept the arguments `func(*args, **kwargs)` my function doesnt contains inputs, is it because of `self` ?

Comment: It makes sure that you can wrap any function regardless of any required or non-required arguments, and yes, `self` is an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As it's written now, you need a `Handlers` instance to run `Handlers.timeit()`, so you need to instantiate the class and use the `timeit()` method of the instance to decorate the methods in your other classes.

```
h = Handlers()

@h.timeit
def add():
    # ...
```

But I think what you're wanting to do is use the class as a namespace to hold your decorators. In this case you can decorate the decorator methods with `@staticmethod`. After all, the method doesn't actually use an instance of the class for anything.

```
class Handlers():

    @staticmethod
    def timeit(func):
        def timefunc():
            start = time.time()
            func()
            end = time.time()
            print('Time taken: ', end - start)
        return timefunc()
```

Or you could just use it as a plain function outside of any class, or (probably best idea) put it in a separate module that you import.